# Why am I getting a cHash error when using routeEnhancers in TYPO3 10.4?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-10.x

Using TYPO3 10.4 I am trying to create a download link in the edit form of a record which leads the user to a download page. I use a routeEnhancer to tell the plugin which file to get but all I get is a cHash error.

[image]

My config.yaml

```xml
routeEnhancers:
  recorddownload:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages: [2]
    routePath: '/{recordUid}'
    namespace: 'tx_myext_xlsx'
    defaults:
      type: '53173'
    requirements:
      recordUid: '[0-9]+'
```

My setup.typoscript

```php
xlsx = PAGE
xlsx {
    typeNum = 53173
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = true
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type: application/octet-stream
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    }
    10 < tt_content.list.20.myext_xlsx
}
```

Opening the page like `http://localhost/autogenerated-1/downloadRecord/`
works fine and returns what is expected from the controller using an input of `0`.
But `http://localhost/autogenerated-1/downloadRecord/0` and every other number throws this cHash error.

Answer (score 0):

I only added a simple

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError'] = false;
```

in my ext_localconf.php

That was all. Done. Problem solved.